# React Store with dynamic callback method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

Let's say I have a component with a method used by a store as a callback, like this:

```
MyComponent = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function() {
        MyStore.addLoginListener(this.userHasAuthenticated);
    },

    render: function(){
        return <div>Hello</div>
    },

    userHasAuthenticated: function(){
        this.setState({
            user: MyStore.getUser()     
        });             
    }
});
```

I will have MyStore with

```
addLoginListener: function(callback) {
    this.on(MessageConstants.LOGIN, callback);
}
```

This works perfectly and MyComponent actually reacts to store changes. The problem is, I want to do this with a dynamic callback:

```
# MyComponent
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.bindMethods();
    MyStore.addLoginListener(this.userHasAuthenticated.bind(this)); // bind this so taht the callback will be evaluated to native code
},

bindMethods: function() {
    if(/* logic checks */){
        this['userHasAuthenticated'] = function(){
            this.setState({
                dynamicKey: dynamicMethod()
            });
            // this should evalutae to the same as the example above
        }
    }
},
```

This does not work anymore. Calling the dynamic method manually works but using it as callback in the store triggers an error: I get

```
TypeError: this.on is not a function
```

It seems therefore that the method is not evaluated correclty by the store (it is passed uninstantiated). The result is the same if I remove bind(this) from this.userHasAuthenticated.bind(this)? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: It's probably a binding issue. `this['userHasAuthenticated'] = function() { ... }.bind(this);`

Comment: Thanks rossipedia, it is indeed a binding problem. Calling this in MyStore results in calling something else...